# How include a List of Abbreviations (acronyms) with memoir?

Tags: memoir, acronyms

I would like a "List of Abbreviations" at the beginning of my PhD thesis, which is being typeset with the memoir document class. Memoir comes with glossaries functionality, but from the manual it seems acronyms are not included in this. The external glossaries package does not work as intended when combined with memoir when I try to use its interface (some commands are identical).

How would one make have automatic acronym handling with memoir?

---

#### Edit: Added MWE

The MWE below actually works as intended. However, I cannot get it to work in my actual project. The acronym is defined correctly, and is shown correctly in the text, but the printed glossaries do not show up. I guess I have to do some debugging.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\date{}
\author{Test}
\title{MWE memoir glossaries}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{dft}{DFT}{density functional theory}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \printglossaries

\mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}
    One of the most used methods in quantum chemistry is \acrfull{dft}.

\end{document}
```

---

#### My custom packages and definitions

```
%%%% file UiTThesis.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{UiTThesis}[2020/06/19 v0.1 UiT PhD Thesis]

% Check that the memoir class is loaded
\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\let\endUiTThesis\relax}{\let\endUiTThesis\endinput
    \PackageError{UiTThesis}{The UiTThesis package only works with the memoir class}%
    {\@ehd}}

% Load packages
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{todonotes}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\RequirePackage[oldstylenums,
                %light,
                largesmallcaps]
                {kpfonts}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,
                linkcolor=blue,
                citecolor=red,
                urlcolor=black,
                linktoc=page]
                {hyperref}
\RequirePackage[capitalize,
                noabbrev]
                {cleveref}
                
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,
                maxcitenames=99,
                mincitenames=1,
                style=numeric-comp,
                maxbibnames=99,
                giveinits=false,
                hyperref=true,
                uniquelist=false,
                uniquename=false,
                sorting=none]
                {biblatex}

% Page layout
\setstocksize{240mm}{170mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2cm}{3cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}

% Float caption style
\captionnamefont{\scshape\bfseries\color{blue}}
\changecaptionwidth
\captionwidth{0.8\textwidth}

% Custom commands
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\newlength{\numberheight}
\makechapterstyle{brakestad}{%
    \setlength{\numberheight}{30pt}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{10pt}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\scshape\Large}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\HUGE}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\bfseries\LARGE}
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{\\[\baselineskip]}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering\chapnamefont\chaptername}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
        \resizebox{!}{\numberheight}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}
        }
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering\hrule\vspace{0.75\onelineskip}}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\vskip\midchapskip\hrule\vspace{0.75\onelineskip}}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vspace{0.75\onelineskip}\hrule\vspace{2\baselineskip}}
}

% Lengths and commands used for defining paper title pages
\newlength{\beforepapernumskip}
\newlength{\beforepapernameskip}
\newlength{\beforepaperdetailskip}
\newcommand*{\papernumfont}{\bfseries\scshape\Huge}
\newcommand*{\papernamefont}{\bfseries\Large}
\newcommand*{\paperdetailfont}{\normalfont}

% Command for adding paper title pages
% Arguments:
% 1: paper page heading (e.g. Paper I)
% 2: Actual title of the paper
% 3: All authors on paper
% 4: The journal
% 5: URL to Supporting Information
\newcommand{\AddPaperTitlePage}[5]{%
    \begin{titlingpage*}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \begin{flushright}
    \setlength\beforepapernumskip{30pt}
    \setlength\beforepapernameskip{5\baselineskip}
    \setlength\beforepaperdetailskip{2\baselineskip}
    
    \vspace*{\beforepapernumskip}
    {\papernumfont#1}
    
    \vspace{\beforepapernameskip}
    {\papernamefont#2}
    
    \vspace{\beforepaperdetailskip}
    {\paperdetailfont#3}\\[2\baselineskip]
    {\paperdetailfont#4}\\[10mm]
    
    %\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{./figs/CBS-O-METER}
    
    \vfill
    {\paperdetailfont Supporting Information Available At: \\ \url{#5}}
    
    \end{flushright}
\end{titlingpage*}
}

% Commands for genertring the paper title pages (orange pages)
\newcommand*{\PaperOneLongTitle}{Static Polarizabilities at the Basis Set Limit: A Benchmark of 124 Species}
\newcommand*{\PaperOneShortTitle}{Paper I}
\newcommand*{\PaperOneAuthors}{Anders Brakestad, Stig Rune Jensen, Peter Wind, Marco D'Alessandro, Luigi Genovese, Kathrin H. Hopmann, and Luca Frediani}
\newcommand*{\PaperOneJournal}{\textit{J. Chem. Theory Comput.} \textbf{16} (2020), 4874--4882, \\ %
    \href{https://www.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00128}{\textsc{doi}: 10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00128}}
\newcommand*{\PaperOneSI}{https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00128?goto=supporting-info}
%-----------------------------------
\newcommand*{\PaperTwoLongTitle}{...}
\newcommand*{\PaperTwoShortTitle}{Paper II}
\newcommand*{\PaperTwoAuthors}{...}
\newcommand*{\PaperTwoJournal}{\textit{J. Chem. Phys.} \textbf{00} (2021), 00--00, \\ %
    \href{https://tinyurl.com/ygnht4b8}{One Awesome Paper}}
\newcommand*{\PaperTwoSI}{www.google.com}
%------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\PaperThreeLongTitle}{title}
\newcommand*{\PaperThreeShortTitle}{Paper III}
\newcommand*{\PaperThreeAuthors}{Anders Brakestad et al}
\newcommand*{\PaperThreeJournal}{\textit{Journal} \textbf{00} (2022), 00--00, \\ %
    \href{www.google.com}{One Awesome Paper}}
\newcommand*{\PaperThreeSI}{www.google.com}



\checkandfixthelayout
\endinput
```

---

#### My master document

```
\documentclass[11pt, 
               twoside, 
               onecolumn, 
               openright, 
               final]{memoir}
               
\usepackage{UiTThesis}
\makeglossaries

\addbibresource{refs/my_papers.bib}
\addbibresource{refs/introduction.bib}

% Commands for generating the unofficial title page
\newcommand*{\thetitle}{Assessing Basis Set Incompleteness Errors in Chemical Properties and Reactivity with MultiWavelets}
\newcommand*{\thesubtitle}{A Bunch of Benchmarks}
\newcommand*{\theauthor}{...}
\newcommand*{\thedate}{\today}
\newcommand*{\formalities}{A Dissertation for the degree of Philosophiae Doctor}
\newcommand*{\Dday}{January, 2022}


% Acronyms
\newacronym{dft}{DFT}{density functional theory}


\begin{document}
    \includepdf{frontpage}
    \cleardoublepage    
    \input{chapters/titlepage_main}

    \frontmatter
        \chapterstyle{brakestad}
        \pagestyle{plain}
        
        \include{chapters/chap_pop}
        \include{chapters/chap_abstract}
        \include{chapters/chap_acks}
        
        \cleardoublepage
        \tableofcontents
        
        \newrefsection
        \include{chapters/chap_lop}
        %\include{chapters/chap_loa}
        \printglossaries
    
    \mainmatter
        \pagestyle{Ruled}
        
        \newrefsection
        \include{chapters/chap_intro}
        \include{chapters/chap_back}
        \include{chapters/chap_pols}
        \include{chapters/chap_nobs}
        \include{chapters/chap_zora}
        \include{chapters/chap_conc}
        
        % Change title of bibliography and then print
        \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
        \cleardoublepage
        \printbibliography
            
    \backmatter
        %\renewcommand*{\appendixname}{Paper}
        \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \cleardoublepage
    
    % Paper 1
    \AddPaperTitlePage{\PaperOneShortTitle}%
                      {\PaperOneLongTitle}%
                      {\PaperOneAuthors}%
                      {\PaperOneJournal}%
                      {\PaperOneSI}
    \cleardoublepage 
    \includepdf[pages=1, noautoscale, scale=.7]{chapters/paper1}
    \cleardoublepage
    
    % Paper 2
    \AddPaperTitlePage{\PaperTwoShortTitle}%
                      {\PaperTwoLongTitle}%
                      {\PaperTwoAuthors}%
                      {\PaperTwoJournal}%
                      {\PaperTwoSI}
    \cleardoublepage 
    \includepdf[pages=1, noautoscale, scale=.7]{chapters/paper2}
    \cleardoublepage

    
    
    % Insert the UiT backpage
    \cleardoublepage
    \includepdf{backpage}
    

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know the `glossaries` package works just fine with `memoir`, if it does not please provide an example.

Comment: Added MWE, but it works in the MWE. I suppose I must do some debugging.

Comment: Yes, as long as you cannot replicate it, it is hard for us to help. Note that, unless stated otherwise `hyperref` has to be the last package loaded as it has to change macros from other packages.

Comment: I added my project files just in case anyone has little to do and would do a quick glance.

Comment: It is not self contained, do we cannot do much with it.